# How to parse upload.responseJSON from Alamofire - swift?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am uploading files to the server using alamofire.  I am successful in uploading these files.  I would like help in parsing response JSON that is fired when the upload is complete.  In the main UIViewController that uploads the file I have set up a Notification.  In the second UIViewcontroller (which I use as a custom popup to present the progress bar), I have setup an Observer to parse the responseJSON. I am not sure exactly how to parse this response JSON.  I have made some tentative step..

UIViewController  1

```
 // 'responseJSON' FIRES WHEN IPLOAD IS
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)

                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: uploadFinishName, object: nil, userInfo: ["response": response])
                }
```

UIViewcontroller 2

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: uploadFinishName, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in

        print("notification.userInfo: \(notification.userInfo)")

        guard
        let userinfo = notification.userInfo as? [String:[AnyHashable:Any]],
        let json = userinfo["response"] as? [AnyHashable:Any] else{
                print("problem")
                return
        }

        print("json: \(json)")


    }
```

In the above code for instance I get back from the console 'problem'.

The responseJSON:

```
 [Request]: POST myDomain/dev/imgpdfuploadrecieve.php
 [Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1c0235860> { URL: myDomain/dev/imgpdfuploadrecieve.php } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
"Content-Length" =     (
    12
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
);
Date =     (
    "Tue, 04 Sep 2018 10:39:32 GMT"
);
Server =     (
    "Apache/2.4.33 (Amazon) PHP/7.2.5"
);
"x-powered-by" =     (
    "PHP/7.2.5"
);
} }
[Data]: 12 bytes
[Result]: SUCCESS: {
code = 104;
}
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 557750367.595, "Initial 
Response Time": 557750367.601, "Request Completed Time": 557750372.791, 
"Serialization Completed Time": 557750372.793, "Latency": 0.007 secs, "Request Duration": 5.196 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.002 secs, "Total Duration": 5.199 secs }
```

Comment: The response is not JSON, it's a Alamofire `DataResponse` object. Please use Quick Help (⌥-click) or go to the definition (⌃⌘-click) to see its properties

Comment: @vadian - you are correct. However, when I type 'response.result' I get only 'SUCCESS'. How do I access 'code = 104'?

Comment: It's an Alamofire `Result` type which contains an enumeration with associated types. Again please read the [documentiation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Result.swift)

Comment: @vadian If you would like to submit the above as an answer I can accept it. might help others with similar problems in the future.  many thanks!